# installation error in shopware-pwa initialization

Tags: progressive-web-apps, shopware

I am trying to install `shopware-pwa`. I am following the steps in `https://github.com/vuestorefront/shopware-pwa`

But at the first step while initializing the project `npx @shopware-pwa/cli init`

While installing I used default option:

```
* Shopware instance address: · https://shopware6-demo.vuestorefront.io
* Shopware instance access token: · SWSCVJJET0RQAXFNBMTDZTV1OQ
* Which version you'd like to use: latest stable (recommended)

Error: Command failed: npx --ignore-existing create-nuxt-app@3.2.0 --answers "{\"name\":\"shopware-pwa-project\",\"description\":\"shopware-pwa-project description\",\"author\":\"Vue Storefront\",\"pm\":\"yarn\",\"ui\":\"none\",\"language\":\"js\",\"server\":\"none\",\"features\":[\"axios\",\"pwa\"],\"linter\":[\"prettier\",\"lintStaged\"],\"test\":\"jest\",\"mode\":\"universal\",\"target\":\"server\",\"devTools\":[],\"gitUsername\":\"\",\"ci\":\"none\"}"
npx: the --ignore-existing argument has been removed.
See `npm help exec` for more information
Trace: Error: Answers JSON could not be parsed (Unexpected token n in JSON at position 1)
    at SAO.runGenerator (/home/user/.npm/_npx/059d932392171cf4/node_modules/sao/lib/index.js:126:15)
    at SAO.run (/home/user/.npm/_npx/059d932392171cf4/node_modules/sao/lib/index.js:101:16)
    at /home/user/.npm/_npx/059d932392171cf4/node_modules/create-nuxt-app/lib/cli.js:51:17
```

Does anybody come up with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found [issue #612](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/612) in the create-nuxt-app GitHub repository.
It seems that after the --answers argument you'd have to start with a sinqle quote (') and then paste your configuration as a JSON. The JSON must not contain any linefeeds/carriage returns and there must not be any whitespaces ( ) between the properties.

So in your case your bash command should look like this:

```
npx --ignore-existing create-nuxt-app@3.2.0 --answers '{"name":"shopware-pwa-project","description":"shopware-pwa-project description","author":"Vue Storefront","pm":"yarn","ui":"none","language":"js","server":"none","features":["axios","pwa"],"linter":["prettier","lintStaged"],"test":"jest","mode":"universal","target":"server","devTools":[],"gitUsername":"","ci":"none"}'
```

I've tried it on my machine just now and it worked. I only got a warning becausethe `--ignore-existing` argument has been removed.
hope that this solves your problem!

greetings